# Using the not selector for jQuery Mobile

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I do the following:

$('ul').attr('data-role','listview');

And that defaults all my unordered lists to be listviews, but I want to exclude unordered lists that are within a `<nav>` tag, such as:

```
<nav>
<ul>
<li><a href="#">One</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Two</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>
```

Q: How can I change my selector to not include those unordered lists that are inside of the nav element?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can filter out only those `ul`s that are not a direct child of a `nav` by doing:

```
$('ul').not('nav > ul').attr('data-role','listview');
```

Comment: Yeah, the data('role','listview') didn't work for me.  I had to use attr('data-role','listview').

Comment: Oh.. Thats strange. Which version of jQuery are you using?

Comment: @Phillip `data('role', 'listview')` will not set the actual attribute `data-role`. So if you read this attribute from external code you will need to use the `attr` function. The `data()` function works only with the jQuery object and not the DOM itself (except for reading).

Comment: I'm using the latest 1.x version.  Hey, that reminds me - I'm going to ask another SO question now...